# LibGDX - Actor group on scrollable table

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

In my game I want to draw a 2-column table which contains squares (like cards), and over them, one image and two labels (as a row, at the top of the card the image, below it one label and below it the other one).

If I put only images in my scrollable table, I get the desired result, but now I'm trying to add the image and the label over the background.

I have tried defining an Actor group and adding it to the table, but some elements doesn't appear, also extending the Image class and drawing the other elements inside the onDraw method, but then the text doesn't move with the card background as the user scrolls.

My table code is as follows:

```
Table scrollTable = new Table();
    scrollTable.align(Align.topLeft);

    scrollTable.add(new HighScoreItem(game, Colors.ORANGE, "1º:FER", 30))
            .width(190).height(150).space(30);
    scrollTable.add(new HighScoreItem(game, Colors.ORANGE, "1º:FER", 30))
            .width(190).height(150).space(30);
    scrollTable.row();

    scrollTable.add(new HighScoreItem(game, Colors.ORANGE, "1º:FER", 30))
            .width(190).height(150).space(30);
    scrollTable.add(new HighScoreItem(game, Colors.ORANGE, "1º:FER", 30))
            .width(190).height(150).space(30);
    scrollTable.row();

    scrollTable.add(new HighScoreItem(game, Colors.ORANGE, "1º:FER", 30))
            .width(190).height(150).space(30);
    scrollTable.add(new HighScoreItem(game, Colors.ORANGE, "1º:FER", 30))
            .width(190).height(150).space(30);
    scrollTable.row();

    scrollTable.add(new HighScoreItem(game, Colors.ORANGE, "1º:FER", 30))
            .width(190).height(150).space(30);
    scrollTable.add(new HighScoreItem(game, Colors.ORANGE, "1º:FER", 30))
            .width(190).height(150).space(30);
    scrollTable.row();

    scrollTable.add(new HighScoreItem(game, Colors.ORANGE, "1º:FER", 30))
            .width(190).height(150).space(30);
    scrollTable.add(new HighScoreItem(game, Colors.ORANGE, "1º:FER", 30))
            .width(190).height(150).space(30);
    scrollTable.row();

    ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane(scrollTable);
    Table table = new Table();
    table.setBounds(33, 10, 410, 500);
    table.add(scroller).fill().expand();

    getStage().addActor(table);
```

HighscoreItem is the class I use in order to display a table item. If I replace this class with a regular Scene2D Image class everything displays just fine, but trying to add the other image and the two labels over the background (by making HighScoreItem extend from Group or by making it extend from Image) is the problem.
Any ideas on how to do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render the actors on top of each other you can use the stack class.

```
Stack stack = new Stack();
stack.add( new Image( new Texture( "test.png" ) ) );
stack.add( new Label( "label 1", skin ) );
stack.add( new Label( "label 2", skin ) );
scrollTable.add( stack );
```

The offset is from the top left of the stack.